# Trying to align svg image hexagons via html and css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmkfS.png

I need the hexagons to remain external images because I want to customize them a lot.

I need to make something that will work no matter the number of hex on a line and no matter the number of lines.

I have tried this:

```css
.line {
  height: 43px;
}

.line.evenLine {
  left: 18px;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Page title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="body">
    <div class="line">
      <svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg>
    </div>
    <div class="line evenLine">
      <svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg>
    </div>
    <div class="line evenLine">
      <svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg>
    </div>

    <p>End</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see in the CSS, I tried to put the even lines 10 pixels higher so that the hex can overlap each other.
However it's not enough. I need the second line to be -10px, the third line to be -20px, the fourth line to be -30px, etc. I can do it easily in JS. But I would like something more neat.

Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change `top` to `margin-top` , and add a `margin-bottom` of `-10px`, this will off-set the negative margin-top, and your hexagonal lines will fit snugly together.. see snippet.

```css
.line {
  height: 43px;
}

.line.evenLine {
  left: 18px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom:-10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Page title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="body">
    <div class="line">
      <svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg>
    </div>
    <div class="line evenLine">
      <svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg>
    </div>
    <div class="line evenLine">
      <svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg><svg width="36" height="43" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon points="0,10 18,0 36,10 36,33 18,43 0,33"
        stroke="black" fill="red" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg>
    </div>

    <p>End</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```